# Java - Listener for a method on a specific object

Tags: java

Is it possible to create a listener for a method on a specific object.

Object A creates Object B. Object A wants to know when B.drive() is called, but doesn't care about when Object C (same class as B) C.drive() is called.

Comment: Sure it is possible. Use the Observer pattern, perhaps?

Comment: maybe use ID to Identify each object and based on the ID you can decide

Comment: If you're using a container it's possible to use [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to solve that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, tipical use of listener pattern is listening to specific object. So create in class of Object B and C method `setListener(SomeClassListener listener)` and in method `drive` of class check if listener was set, if yes run method from listener.

As I understand Your situation A object implements Factory pattern - it creates objects, so object A should be also **Listener** and when it create object B call `b.setListener(a)`, when create object C not call this method.

Eventually if creation shoud be inside object A ( should be!) create in class of object A factory method with parameter:

```
SomeClass createObj(boolean setListener){

     SomeClass obj=new SomeClass();
     if (setListener){

        obj.setListener(this);
     }

     return obj;
}
```

So for object B creation will look like:

```
SomeClass b=a.createObj(true);
```

For object C ( not listen )

```
SomeClass c=a.createObj();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of the listener pattern.

```
public class ObjectA implements DriveListener {

    //defined in interface DriveListener
    @Override
    public void onDrive(ObjectB source){
        doSomething();
    }

    // a simple factory creating ObjectB instances
    public ObjectB makeB(){
        ObjectB b = new ObjectB();
        b.setListener(this);
        return b;
    }

}

public class ObjectB {

    private DriveListener driveListener;

    public void setListener(DriveListener l){
        this.driveListener = l;
    }

    public void drive() {
        //do something...

        //notify the listener if any.
        if(driverListener!=null){
            driverListener.onDrive(this);
        }
    }
}
```